# YouTube Embed appears to be interfering with CSS dropdown hovers

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

With no code changes in the past few months, the dropdown menus have started behaving weirdly on http://weldtite.co.uk/

The link background should turn red on hover, and a dropdown should appear if there is one. The jQuery that adds a class on hover (for the benefit of IE6 users) is applied. So the CSS looks like this:

```
.primary-item:hover a,
.active a,
.primary-item:hover span,
.active span {
    background-color: #ed1b2d;
    color: #FFF;
}

.primary-item:hover .secondary-nav,
.active .secondary-nav {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

This works fine on all the inner pages.

The homepage however has embedded YouTube videos in it. If I remove the YouTube videos, the menu hover state works. If I put them back in, the menu hover state fails again.

**This seems to only be an issue in Google Chrome (21.0.1180.82), and it only happens sometimes.**

Things I've tried:

- Putting a lower z-index on the iframe.
- Wrapping the iframe in a div and adding a lower z-index to that div.
- Adding ?wmode=transparent and opaque to the video URl.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For some bizarre reason, having CSS3 "transition: all .2s ease-in-out;" on the primary item, and secondary navigation dropdown broke it (but only on the homepage with the YouTube videos. I've changed them to "transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out; / transition: background-color .2s ease-in-out;" and all is well in the world again.

Bizarre.